# docker push to a my-company docker repository

Tags: docker

I have an internal company docker repository.

When I was added to it, I received a repository url of the format:

https://docker.mycompany.com/repositories/myusername/myrepository

Ok. great.

I've created a Dockerfile and I have built the docker image.

> docker build -t business-services:latest .

Everything works.

I do a

> docker images

and I see:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
business-services   latest              aaaaaaaaaaaa        3 hours ago         120MB
openjdk             8-jdk-alpine        bbbbbbbbbbbb        2 weeks ago         103MB
```

Great!

Now I'm trying to push "business-services:latest" to:

https://docker.mycompany.com/repositories/myusername/myrepository

...

Here is where things go awry.

First, before you ask, YES, I did a login.

```
docker login https://docker.mycompany.com/repositories/myusername/myrepository
Username: myusername 
Password: 
Login Succeeded
```

The issue comes when I try to "tag" it and then push it.

It looks like the tag name is some kind of mixture of concerns....between the remote docker repository and the image:release.  :(  Boo.

If I tag it this way:

```
docker tag business-services:latest docker.mycompany.com/repositories/myuserna/business-services:latest
```

and i do docker images I see this:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
business-services                                              latest              aaaaaaaaaaaa        3 hours ago         120MB

docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository/business-services   latest              aaaaaaaaaaaa        3 hours ago         120MB

openjdk                                                        8-jdk-alpine        04060a9dfc39        2 weeks ago         103MB
```

and then try to push it like this

```
docker push docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository/business-services
The push refers to repository [docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository/business-services]

denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

so its confusing the repository name

I did it this way too, just to make sure

```
 docker push docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository/business-services:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository/business-services]

denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

same error :(

Then I tried this:

```
docker tag business-services:latest docker.mycompany.com/business-services:latest

 docker push docker.mycompany.com/business-services:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.mycompany.com/business-services]

denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

That doesn't work because i'm not giving myuser/myrepository in the value.

Gaaaaaaaaaaa

This "mixture" of the remote url and the container name is driving me nuts.

At some point of trying to figure out the string voodoo, I got this error:

```
The push refers to a repository 
An image does not exist locally with the tag:
```

**What is the magic sauce for pushing to a url name like**

**docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository**

and who came up with this mix the target repository WITH the imagename voodoo?

Or am I completely off-base for how to push something to a internal company docker repository

RESEARCH stuff I found below:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/#examples

> Now, push the image to the registry using the image ID. In this
>   example the registry is on host named registry-host and listening on
>   port 5000. To do this, tag the image with the host name or IP address,
>   and the port of the registry:
>
> $ docker tag rhel-httpd registry-host:5000/myadmin/rhel-httpd
>
> $ docker push registry-host:5000/myadmin/rhel-httpd

Yes, I have researched this, thus how I got this far with my journey.

docker --version
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4

Thanks !!

Append

I followed these instructions:

http://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2017/01/25/push-a-docker-image-to-personal-repository/

under the "Push to your private repository" area.

Same error.  can't find the URL

```
docker tag business-services docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository/business-services:latest
docker push docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository/business-services:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.mycompany.com/myusername/myrepository/business-services]

denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: I would ask whoever gave you that repository URL how to use it; it doesn't follow any specific standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got this to work

> docker tag business-services
>   docker.mycompany.com/myusername/business-services:latest
>
> docker push docker.mycompany.com/myusername/business-services:latest

It looks like the "short name" (in this case "business-services")... ~**becomes**~ the repository name.  Or something like that.

and the repository on the docker trusted repository shows up as:

> https://docker.mycompany.com/repositories/myusername/business-services

Anyways.  It looks silly now.  I hope that helps someone in the future.

Comment: gaaaaaaa, i hate marking my own awswer, but in this case....this was the syntax sugar I got working.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other images from this repository? check the tags and make yours similar. Anyway, it is your company internals, it could be configured in different ways and better to ask internal guys who support this repo. Also, ask them to check your permissions.
for example, in my case works something like `artifactory.company.com:10001/myusername/virtualreponame/imagename:latest`
but in your case, it could be completely differ

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the first time I've tried to use it.  It is "mine".  And new.  I'll see if I can find some documentation.

Comment: It is straight up (on premise) version of docker.  Docker Trusted Registry
2.5.3

Comment: vvchik, your example...just didn't work in my scenario.  i (like you) feel like it should.  upvote for giving a suggestion that at least gives another example (and tries to help).  future readers will have at least two options now (yours and my recent answer) . thanks.